# sed command that replaces number and word by two

Tags: sed

1) sed command which puts two of the first 'w' on each line. E.g "hewor" = "hewwor".

and

2) sed command which puts two of the first digit on each line E.g "hew0r" = "hew00r"

For first one I got

```
$ sed s/w/ww/
```

for the second one I don't understand how to replicate the same digit for example I got

```
$ sed s/[0-9]/00/
```

would work but it would have to be zero each time. How do I get the same digit?

Comment: How about reading the manual... You'll learn how to reference the matched portion, regardless of what's in the LHS. ;)

Comment: My bad, I meant $sed s/[0-9]/00/ as you can see, it has to be zero. I'm looking for a way for the digit to be the one found in the [0-9].

Comment: "sed s/[0-9]/\0\0/" does the exact same as "sed s/[0-9]/00/" or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes. It becomes hew4r -> hew00r. I want hew44r. Also, why should I use that instead of "sed s/[0-9]/00/"? For this and the first example?

Comment: OK. in gnu sed using `\0` refers to the previously matched regex. In bsd sed this is done using `&`. So in your case since `\0` does not work, you can use `sed 's/[0-9]/&&/'`. Actuall using `&` will work even in gnu sed.

Comment: This will also work: `sed -E 's/([[:digit:]])/\1\1/'`

Comment: @Tinler the difference between the two forms is that a `&` in the replacement inserts the entire match, while  `\1`, `\2`, etc insert only a matched capture group.  e.g. with `s/the \(capture group\)/&/` vs `s/the \(capture group\)/\1/`. the `&` inserts "the capture group" into the replacement, `\1` inserts only "capture group".  There can be multiple capture groups in a search pattern, and they are referred to in numerical order - `\1` is the first capture group, `\2` is the second, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `sed`'s feature, called [groups](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/10/unix-sed-tutorial-advanced-sed-substitution-examples/) (may be not the best reference, try to search for other tutorials). In you case the solution is

```
sed 's/\([0-9]\)/\1\1/' input_file.txt
```

the regexp for the first group `\([0-9]\)` will match any digit, and the part `\1\1` says to replace the first group with itself repeated twice.

Comment: I don't think the purpose of this assignment is to teach them how to use groups. The link is good though, it has the answer.

Comment: A lot of people helped me here answering my questions when I just began. I am just returning this help.